# Hazelcast issues after injecting istio envoy

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, istio

i'm having issue with hazelcast after enabling istio and i wonder how can i address this.

i have K8s cluster and i've recently installed istio.
when trying to add envoy to deployment with hazelcast i have a wierd issue where i have many coinnections error during rolling upgrade. i should mention eventually the deployment is OK but this errors indicate something is wrong.

i've noticed that without Envoy when i'm doing rolling upgrade to a deployment i see the following:

```
[10.16.17.72]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.16.17.72:45025 and /10.16.5.8:5701
[10.16.5.8]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.16.5.8:5701 and /10.16.17.72:45025

[10.16.17.72]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connection[id=1, /10.16.17.72:45025->/10.16.5.8:5701, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.16.5.8]:5701, alive=false, connectionType=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
[10.16.17.72]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.16.5.8:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /10.16.5.8:5701]
......
[10.16.17.72]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Removing connection to endpoint [10.16.5.8]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Connection refused to address /10.16.5.8:5701}, Error-Count: 5
[10.16.17.72]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Member [10.16.5.8]:5701 - 945ec2c8-fc56-4624-aab3-de9823d4886a is suspected to be dead for reason: No connection
```

what happens here is:

- new pod starting and joining the cluster.
- connection initialize between old-pod:5701 to new-pod:xxx (2 directions)
- new pod complains it cannot reach old pod (connectionType=MEMBER) , and after 5 attempts
  consider it as dead and remove it from the cluster
- old pod removed once rolling upgrade completes.

now, when i'm doing the same while injecting Envoy so i have 2 containers in this pod deployment, i've noticed the following:

```
[10.16.3.244]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.16.3.244:5701 and **/127.0.0.6:48287**
[10.16.5.16]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.16.5.16:59827 and /10.16.3.244:5701

[10.16.5.16]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connection[id=1, /10.16.5.16:59827->/10.16.3.244:5701, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.16.3.244]:5701, alive=false, connectionType=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
```

but then i get million of messages like the following:

```
[10.16.5.16]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connection[id=2, /10.16.5.16:33659->/10.16.3.244:5701, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.16.3.244]:5701, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
```

the first 'Connection closed' message was MEMBER type and was on the same mentioned connection we have on the initializtion message (10.16.5.16:59827 --> 10.16.3.244:5701)

but the rest of the messages are from random ports on 10.16.5.16 to the old pod.
i assume the reason for this is the init message the indicate Initialized new cluster connection between
`/10.16.3.244:5701 and **/127.0.0.6:48287**` it configured the connection to wrong host:port instead of to 10.16.5.16:59827.

rolling upgrade completes the same but the log is full with million of messages from that kind.

i've reproduced the same and saw also non-matched ports:

```
I 2021-02-09T08:18:40.163Z  [10.16.5.22]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.16.5.22:49213 and /10.16.5.21:5701
I 2021-02-09T08:18:40.158Z  [10.16.5.21]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.16.5.21:5701 and /10.16.5.22:46274
```

how can i prevent this ? why this part of getting the remoteAddress gets different port?
i've tried so far the following:

- upgrade to 4.1.1 , nothing changed
- added JHIPSTER_SLEEP , didnt helped
- updated the deployment to make sure the proxy starts before the application, didnt helped.

any idea?

Thanks
Chen

Comment: Does this happen only during rolling upgrade? Do you have deployed hazelcast as StatefulSet or Deployment?

Comment: yes only during redeployment and this is deployment.

Comment: What is the rolling strategy you are using? Based off hz docs, when deploying hazelcast as Deployment you may need to check the rolling strategy to avoid split brain. Wondering if that's what is causing any issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling Upgrades of Hazelcast is an enterprise feature and you need a license key. If you already have one then you should be checking this with Hazelcast support.